# How can I remove rows from one csv file that are not in another using PHP?

Tags: php, r, csv

I have two different .csv files, each with the same 11 columns. Is there a way using PHP that I could remove rows from file A that are not in file B? Alternatively, is there a way to do this in R? Im using the files to do a cost prediction and the model breaks if there are rows in A that are not in B. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will be glad to help you if you get stuck on a *specific* programming problem, but we are not here to write code or design your system for you. You will need to at least make an attempt at solving your own issue. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to quickly create a reproducible example so others can help. Please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: Im not looking for you to write my code, just a suggestion.